# Pause & Resume live video capture from webcam using DirectX.capture

Tags: c#, windows, directx, video-capture

hi i am following this link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx

to capture data from webcam.Its working fine but when i pause and do resume then the file that contains data, its size increases but old data is lost and only new data persists.

can anybody point me towards a working example/tutorial where pause feature works.

i tried/searched many links but still landed nowhere.

can anybody provide me some help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the pause behavior of directShow.net but somehow it did not worked.

when i paused a avi file was created and when i resumed i found that the new contents are written on the previous file. the size of the file increased but the older content was washed away.

So i tried this:

```
1) When i paused a file say test.avi was generated.
2) when i resumed i renamed test to test1.avi and created new test.avi 
file and merged them when user clicks on stop.
```

In this way i achieved pause feature. though its indirect but its still working for me..
hope i could implement the direct way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of comments about this in the article:

[Searching "pause" inside the article comments](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directxcapture.aspx?msg=1250924#xx1250924xx)

[All search results for "pause" in the article comments](http://www.codeproject.com/Search.aspx?fid=14156&q=pause)

Comment: Thanks CharlesB for the links but the comments did not solved my problem.Whenever i click on pause an ew avi file is generated.If i click on resume then new file is created discarding the old saved one.Iam trying to rename and keep the copies and merging them when user stops the reording.Lets c how it works.If u have any other ideas den do lemme know.Till then i am trying....

Comment: Charles still pause functionality cannot be achieved, every time when i pause the stream and then resume the size of the file definitley increases but it does not contains the previous data.its lost.can u help.The links u provided cldnt help me.

Comment: @Swati Can't help you as I don't know DirectX, but edit your question with the problem you have and surely you'll get help from others